# How to use currency from other column for formatting in “Accounting” in EXCEL for one column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

[image]

I have numeric data for revenue in column A, and text data as currency code (e.g.  $) in column B.  The currency in column B is not constant, we are pulling it from database.

In column C i want a revenue data formatted in "accounting" format with the use of currency in column B. How can I change the format in column C, based on the text value in column B, for that row?

Comment: please post a screenshot of your data. it will assist us greatly in assisting you.

Comment: Added the image.  @ScottHoltzman

Comment: you won't be able to use the `accounting` format directly, but you can mock it up with the following formula: `=B2&"    "&TEXT(A2,"0.00")` And since it's text you will not be able to sum it up. It could be possible with a VBA custom UDF, if you are open to that.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, with this formula I am able to see the appended value of currency in revenue. However when I am selecting the column it is showing the count at bottom and NOT the sum.  I required the sum to be shown at bottom when I select the column.

Comment: see my edited comment Mohit. Since you are working with text you will not be able to sum this data. There is no way except possibly with a VBA custom UDF. Also, why can't you just get the sum from column A? And why would you want to sum different currencies anyway? What is the need to have them be numbers? If you tell me the need, perhaps there is another work around to achieve the results you need.

Comment: A more comprehensive solution is this: `=TEXT(A2,"_("&B2&"*     #,##0.00_);_("&B2&"*     (#,##0.00);_("&B2&"*     ""-""??_);_(@_)")`. This mimics the custom format for the `accounting` style and accounts for negative numbers.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman  I am getting numeric data (revenue) in column A and the currency of that data in column B.  Both the values coming from database, so it might be different currencies in column B.  I want to append the currency and revenue in column C and if user select the  entire column C then the auto sum should visible in bottom of excel. Can we achieve this ?
Thanks for your help 

Comment: Mohit - please read my comments again. If you have more questions let me know. You simply restated your original question in your last comment.

Comment: OK thanks Scott .  I am appreciate your help.  @ScottHoltzman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a few simple Conditional Formatting rules. Conditional Formatting is a set of rules which you can apply to a number of cells - if those rules result in TRUE, then the special formatting applies (including highlighting, number format, etc.).

Go to the Home Ribbon > Styles > Conditional Formatting > New Rule

Then you can select all of column C for your new rule, defined as follows:

```
=B1="$"
```

What this means is, relative to C1, if B1 is "$", the equation will produce TRUE, and the special formatting will apply. Because I used "B1" & not "B$1", C2 will look at B2, C3 will look at B3, and so on.

The formatting rules should be set to format as Accounting, with $ as the currency. Then create additional rules exactly the same, for Euros, etc.

You can save yourself having to make one of the rules, by first setting the formatting to column B to one of the formats - ie: Accounting with "$". Then that will be the default format to apply if no Conditional Formatting results in True.

Then for the actual values in column C, just make C1 = A1, and drag down.

Comment: Hi Grade, 

Thanks for the help its working correct.

Here every time for each currency we need to create a separate rule to have that currency in accounting format.  
Can we do it in such a way that it will decide the currency in accounting format based on the currency we get in the column B ?
In more detail here we are hardcoding the value of “$” in formula and for that formula we are selecting the format and for euro we need to create another rule and so on. But in my sheet I am going to receive all type of currency. So can’t we make it generic ?   Appreciate your help 

Comment: @Mohit Without using VBA, I don't think it will be possible to re-format with a generic rule, unless you do what Scott has suggested, meaning your new cells would look correct but would actually be text values. You could put in whatever currencies you think would be most likely now, and then as new ones come up, add new rules.

Comment: I have added the "Conditional Formatting" for the column of PIVOT table, the formatting working fine all rows except the last seven rows.  I have applied the conditional formatting for all the rows of PIVOT table, it is not getting applied to last seven rows.  Any suggestion ?